# How to Insert a static value into a column in MS Access during a query

Tags: ms-access

I am currently switching data sources for one of my databases, now the old data used to include a column called 'Counter' every row had a 1 in it, this 1 was then used in excel formulas and summary pages as well as pivot tables, So that I don't have to go through the process of finding all these formulas and fixing them I would like for MS Access to insert a '1' Value into this column when the append is completed however I don't know how to go about it, or if Access can do it.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, Access can do such a thing using standard SQL syntax... just place a literal value 1 in place of a column reference.  If you need further assistance, at least include the SQL of your append query so that we can build upon what you already have instead of plucking examples from air.  More specifically, what do you mean by "when the append is completed"?  You can include the literal 1 value in the same/original append command, so there is likely no need to execute redundant commands after the original append.